# 'Cannot GET /api/items'

Tags: node.js, express

Working on a MERN application as a way to learn how it all works, but I am stuck trying to get my routes to display. I don't get any other errors, and if I use a simple `app.get('/')`, I am able to see that just fine; it seems that the routes I have defined are not being recognized for some reason.

```js
require('dotenv').config();

const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT;

const options = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:8081'
}

app.use(cors(options));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const db = require('./models');
db.mongoose
    .connect(db.url, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
    })
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Successfully connected.');
    })
    .catch((error) =>{
        console.log(`Connection failed. Error: ${error}`);
        process.exit();
    }
);

require('./routes/items.routes')(app)

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening at localhost:${port}`);
});
```

```js
const multer = require('multer');
const dir = './public/';

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, dir);
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        const fileName = file.originalname.toLowerCase().split(' ').join('-');
        cb(null, fileName + '-' + Date.now());
    }
});

var upload = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
        if (file.mimetype == 'image/png' || file.mimetype == 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype == 'image/jpeg') {
            cb(null, true);
        } else {
            cb(null, false);
            return cb(new Error('Invalid file type.'));
        }
    }
});

module.exports = app => {
    const items = require('../controllers/items.controller');

    let router = require('express').Router();

    router.post('/', upload.single('icon'), items.create);
    router.delete('/:id', items.delete);

    app.use('/api/items', router);
};
```

I followed [this](https://www.bezkoder.com/node-express-mongodb-crud-rest-api/#Setup_Express_web_server) and [this](https://www.positronx.io/react-file-upload-tutorial-with-node-express-and-multer/) as a start point. Unsure what I am missing or why it is unable to retrieve my POST route.

Comment: How are you testing your post route?

Comment: I don't think I know how to test it? How would I do that?

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in your title:

```
Cannot GET /api/items
```

means it is a GET request to `/api/items`.  But, you don't have a GET handler for that route.  You only have a POST handler for that route defined with these two lines of code:

```
router.post('/', upload.single('icon'), items.create);
app.use('/api/items', router);
```

So, you apparently need to change your test on that route to a POST, not a GET and the POST will be expecting a body part with the data for an icon in it.

---

If you want to see exactly what is getting to your router (for debugging/troubleshooting purposes), you can add this right after you declare the router as the first item you register on the router.

```
router.use((req, res, next) => {
    console.log(`In router: ${req.method}:${req.originalUrl}`);
    next();
});
```

Comment: I added a GET and now I am encountering this error: ``TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined`` at ``Item.find().then(data => {...``. I assume it is because I still do not have any data inserted into my API, but how would I be able to POST any information if I cannot even get the page to display anything? I don't think I understand.

Comment: @waifuxszn - That error sounds like Item is not defined.  You don't show that code so not much else we can offer

Comment: Good news, figured out that the undefined portion of the error was due to me incorrectly importing my model. It seems to be working, but I have to ask, since I have not connected any front-end framework to the backend at the moment, and my GET and POST are on the same path, I shouldn't see any sort of form or anything to fill in data, correct? Also, thank you for taking the time to reply! I appreciate it.

Comment: @waifuxszn - there's no automatic form.  If you want one, you have to put it in your front end pages.

Comment: I figured as much, just wanted to be sure. Thanks for the help!